# search for date/time in multiple files

Tags: linux, windows, date, search, grep

Is there a command/script in linux or iwindows that will search through a list of TXT file and pull out any Date/time value found within those files and export it to a TXT which will contain the date/time and the filename it came from?

Thanks

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: Only if you specify format of a date you are loking for. If you hava format for example yyyymmdd you could use for loop and awk with regular expression. This can be done in linux.

Comment: @haifzhan this is an example of the date/time that exists within the TXT files:

19/06/2015 13:49:26

Comment: @dabal this is an example of the date/time that exists within the TXT files: 19/06/2015 13:49:26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with GNU grep for years from 1000 to 9999:

```
grep -Eo '[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[1-9][0-9]{3} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' file
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: would you mind explaining what this part of the regex means : /[1-9][0-9]{3}    i understood the other parts but this one is a bit confusing

Comment: This match a slash followed by a digit (range 1 to 9) followed by three digits (range 0 to 9). Longer version: `/[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Comment: See: [rick.measham.id.au](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%2F[1-9][0-9]{3})